# Removing adsense from Blogger posts

Tags: html, css, blogger, adsense

I have one adsense unit in each post, entered manually.

The code is like this:

```
<div id="toppostad" style="float: left">
Adsense code
</div>
```

When i placed the code i gave the div an id, thinking that if i would want to remove it in the future i would just use display:none; and that would do it. But now after i did some research it seems that it is against adsense police to use display:none.

Is there any other way to remove the code? Manualy it will take me forever, because i have like 10000+ posts, and after i edit 100+ posts, blogger freezes and i must wait like an hour for it to work again.

I found some scripts here, but none of them worked for blogger.

Answer (score 0):

"The special AdSense tab in Blogger's Template section does not currently have a way to automatically remove ads for you. So if, for some reason, you decide you no longer want to display ads on your blog, you'll need to remove the code manually."

Another way to remove the code it to reset your template to one of the default versions. This is easier than looking through the code yourself, but please note that it will also remove any other customizations your changes you have made. :/

Comment: Reseting the template will not do anything. The adsense code is inserted inside each post, manually. Only way i can think of, is some kind of java script that will prevent the div to be loaded... but i no nothing about scripting, and that is why i asked here.

Comment: what about disabling adsense from blogger dashboard page or disabling the ad unit from adsense page.

Comment: there is no way to disable the ads from adsense settings, ya i know doesn't make sense... Anyway i ended up by manually editing each post, i was a hard job but i've done it...